# how can asp.net mvc3 receive mp3 file sent by flash (application/x-amf)

Tags: flash, asp.net-mvc-3, actionscript, amf

when I use the *Request.InputStream* in MVC3 action method to save the file sent by action script I got a corrupted file. When I used firebug to trace the request I realized that the Content-type is **"application/x-amf"** and has the file name at the end of the stream. knowing that I can't change the action script I need a way to save the file correctly to disk.

Comment: AMF != MP3. You are receiving a [serialized Flash item](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format), not an MP3 file.

Comment: I came across fluorinefx but I need a sample how to save the sent file on server side using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to save time I encoded the byte array into base64 string and sent it to server. Then decoded it on the server side and saved the file. It works fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to handle it the same way that I do in the [VoiceModel project](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/) when an IVR sends an audio file in a POST.  Here is the code used in the controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveRecording(HttpPostedFileBase CallersMessage)
    {
        if (CallersMessage != null && CallersMessage.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(CallersMessage.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(recordingPath), fileName);
            CallersMessage.SaveAs(path);
        }

        string vm_id = Request.QueryString["vm_id"];
        string vm_event = Request.QueryString["vm_event"];
        string vm_result = "";
        return VoiceView(vm_id, vm_event, vm_result);
    }
```

VoiceModel is an open source project and you can download the code and examples on [CodePlex](http://voicemodel.codeplex.com/releases).  The "Recording Example" shows how to use this feature.

Comment: Thank you for your response, But when I take **HttpPostedFileBase** as a parameter for action method it evaluates to null. The only way to get the byte array is using **Request.InputStream**

Comment: If you just used the variable name CallersMessage it will not match up.  The variable name needs to match the name of the item in the POST that contains the audio file. You can use something like Fiddler [http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/] to see what Flash is sending in the POST message.